# What load balancing policies are available in Cassandra Java driver 4.x?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

We are upgrading datastax Cassandra java driver from 3.2 to 4.x to support DSE 6.8.
Load balancing policies our application currently supports are RoundRobinPolicy and DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.
These policies aren't available in java-driver-core 4.12.
How can we support the above policies.Please help..
Current code in our application using cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:

```
public static LoadBalancingPolicy getLoadBalancingPolicy(String loadBalanceStr, boolean isTokenAware) {
        LoadBalancingPolicy loadBalance = null;
        if (isTokenAware) {
            loadBalance = new TokenAwarePolicy(loadBalanceDataConvert(loadBalanceStr));
        } else {
            loadBalance = loadBalanceDataConvert(loadBalanceStr);
        }
        
        return loadBalance;
        
    }
private static LoadBalancingPolicy loadBalanceDataConvert(String loadBalanceStr) {
        if (CassandraConstants.CASSANDRACONNECTION_LOADBALANCEPOLICY_DC.equals(loadBalanceStr)) {
            return new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder().build();
        } else if (CassandraConstants.CASSANDRACONNECTION_LOADBALANCEPOLICY_ROUND.equals(loadBalanceStr)) {
            return new RoundRobinPolicy();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I think I would take a step back and first determine what need is driving the desire for the round robin policies - you are right that the new driver does not have round robin, but there are very few instances where you would want a policy that was deliberately token un-aware. Can you expand the question to provide the context?

Comment: Thank you very much for responding @Andrew.Our existing application uses RoundRobin and DCAwareRoundRobin load balancing policies.From what I understand,DCAwareRoundRobin policy tries connecting to remote nodes after all nodes in local datacenter has been tried and failed.But,we donot have this option in datastax 4.0,as we can only connect to a single datacenter.How can we achieve connecting to remote nodes in datacenter2 when datacenter1 has failed?And also,how to achieve tokenaware load balancing policy,as the TokenAwarePolicy class also doesn't exist in java-driver-core 4.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load balancing has been heavily simplified in version 4.x of the Cassandra Java driver. You no longer need to nest multiple policies within each other to achieve high availability.

In our opinion, the best policy is the `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy` which is enabled by default and achieves all the best attributes as the policies in older versions.

The `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy` generates a query plan that is token-aware by default so replicas which own the data appear first and prioritised over other nodes in the local DC. For token-awareness to work, you must provide routing information either by keyspace (with `getRoutingKeyspace()`), or by routing key (with `getRoutingKey()`).

If routing information is not provided, the `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy` generates a query plan that is a simple round-robin shuffle of available nodes in the local DC.

We understand that developers who are used to configuring `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy` in older versions would like to continue using it but we do not recommend it. It is our opinion that failover should take place at the infrastructure layer, not the application layer.

Our opinion is that the `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy` is the right choice in all cases. If you prefer to configure DC-failover, make sure you fully understand the implications and know that we think it is the wrong choice.

For details, see the following documents:

- [Java driver v4 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/upgrade_guide/)
- [Load Balancing in Java driver v4](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/)