# How do I enable cross-datacenter failover programatically in the Cassandra Java driver v4?

Tags: cassandra, load-balancing, datastax-java-driver

In datastax driver 3.x,we've DCAwareRoundRobin policy,which tries to connect to remote nodes if nodes in local datacenter fails.In the datastax drvier 4.x,we donot have that policy and confines to local-only.But,in the datastax docs,it's mentioned as:

```
Cross-datacenter failover is enabled with the following configuration option:
datastax-java-driver.advanced.load-balancing-policy.dc-failover {
  max-nodes-per-remote-dc = 2
}
```

The driver will then attempt to open connections to nodes in remote datacenter.But,in the driver,we specify only a single datacenter to connect to as below:

```
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
    .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 9042))
    .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("5.6.7.8", 9042))
    .withLocalDatacenter("datacenter1")
    .build();
```

How the connection to remote datacenter is handled?Please help..

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is you don't do it programatically -- the Java driver does it for you after you've enabled `advanced.load-balancing-policy.dc-failover`.

The contact points are just the initial hosts the driver "contacts" to discover the cluster topology. After it has collected metadata about the cluster, it knows about nodes in remote DCs.

Since you've configured `max-nodes-per-remote-dc = 2`, the driver will add 2 nodes from each remote DC to the end of the query plan. The nodes in the local DC will be listed first then followed by the remote nodes. If the driver can't contact the nodes in the local DC, then it will start contacting the remote nodes in the query plan, one node at a time until it runs out of nodes to contact.

But I have to reiterate what I said in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662415/), **we do not recommend enabling DC-failover**. For anyone else coming across this answer, you've been warned. Cheers!